# converting date and time "strtotime()" question

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, strtotime

Why "strtotime()" still display date and time even though the database table is null?

and how to not display "strtotime" if the database table is null?

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE logtrail(
login_id INT(100) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
admin_id INT(100),
first_name VARCHAR(100),
last_name VARCHAR(100),
dateandtime_login  DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
dateandtime_logout DATETIME
);
```

PHP code for displaying:

```
  <?php 
          $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM logtrail ORDER BY login_id DESC";
          $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
          $logtrail = mysqli_num_rows($result1);

          if($logtrail > 0 ){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1) ) {

            $dateandtime_login = strtotime($row['dateandtime_login']);
            $dateandtime_logout = strtotime($row['dateandtime_logout']);

          ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['login_id'] ?></td> 
              <td><?php echo $row['admin_id'] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['first_name'], $row['last_name'] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo date('F d Y', $dateandtime_login) ?></td>
              <td><?php echo date('h:i A', $dateandtime_login) ?></td>
              <td><?php echo date('h:i A', $dateandtime_logout) ?></td>
          </tr>
    <?php }} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the values returned from the database are empty. Otherwise, the date function will return the standard date (December 31 1969).

Sample:

```
echo ($dateandtime_login != null ? date('F d Y', $dateandtime_login) : false);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways you can do that. What you need to do is check if the value is null and provide a default empty string.

Take a look at two ways I have done that. The first uses `if` statement and the second one uses a ternary operator. The values are prepared before displaying. I strongly recommend to never mix presentation and database logic. Keep them separate. For simplicity, I have not separated them in below example.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM logtrail ORDER BY login_id DESC";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);

foreach ($result1 as $row):
    if ($row['dateandtime_login']) {
        $dt = new DateTime($row['dateandtime_login']);
        $row['date_login'] = $dt->format('F d Y');
        $row['time_login'] = $dt->format('h:i A');
    } else {
        $row['date_login'] = '';
        $row['time_login'] = '';
    }

    $row['dateandtime_logout'] = $row['dateandtime_logout'] ? (new DateTime($row['dateandtime_logout']))->format('h:i A') : '';
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['login_id'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['admin_id'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['first_name'], $row['last_name'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['date_login'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['time_login'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['dateandtime_logout'] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
endforeach;
```

Comment: I don't find it right to use the DateTime class in this code. Formatting the desired date here. For this we must use the format functions, not including a whole class.

I use the DateTime class mostly with the modify method to make the code more readable.

Comment: @sercanarga I don't understand what you mean. `DateTime` class has superseded `strtotime` and `date`. What possible reason could there be to use the more limited functionality? I don't feel right suggesting in my answers the old functions unless it is for something really trivial. In this case, I believe `DateTime` class is the best choice.

Comment: Performance. There is no need to create an entire class for this code.

Comment: I don't think the performance difference would be large enough to be noticed if there is any at all. I find that benefits outweigh any potential and tiny performance cost